# Javascript show div in loop error

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript:

```
function loop()
{
for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
   alert(i);
   var errorDiv;
   errorDiv = document.getElementById("error" + i) ;
   errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="error" style="display: none;"> ABC </div>
<div id="error1" style="display: none;"> ABC </div>
```

Hi guys!

Why i have error in this function? I tried show div in loop, but i get a error if i run this function..

Thanks for help

Comment: You have no div with id of `error0` or `error2`, but your loop will be assuming they exist.

Comment: Omg i'm idiot..
Thank you for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two corrections in your function:

1 - In javascript loop, you're trying to get the div with id `error0` but it does not exist, you need to add it within the HTML.

2 - The loop goes to the number 3, but you have only 2 error divs. Therefor I changed the loop condition to execute while `i<2`:

```
// Adding the number 0 in the id of the div
<div id = "error0" style = "display: none;"> ABC </div>
<div id = "error1" style = "display: none;"> ABC </div>


function loop(){
// Changing the loop condition
   for (i = 0; i <2; i ++)
   {
      alert (i);
 
     var errorDiv = document.getElementById (`error${i}`);
      errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1-you need to call `function loop` 
2-you need to change `id` of `div` **error** by **error1**

Try this code
it working for me

JS:

```
function loop()
{
for (i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
   var errorDiv;
   errorDiv = document.getElementById("error" + i) ;
   errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="loop();">

<div id="error0" style="display: none;"> ABC </div>
<div id="error1" style="display: none;"> ABC </div>

</body>
```